# Return a column value with the input ID

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I was trying to return a column value in a table called with its ID .

```
    public String PenTypes(int?id, Pen pen)
    {
    int num;

      var query = from d in db.Pens
                   where d.ID == 1
                   select d.Type;

      num=Convert.ToInt(query);
      return num;
```

I have no clue as to where i'm going wrong. I do know its simple, but I'm really new to using Entity Framework. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method if you want to get entity by id:

```
  var pen = db.Pens.Find(id);
  if (pen == null)
     // handle case when pen is not found

  return pen.Type; // if type is string, then you possibly need to parse it
```

Or you can use `FirstOrDefault`/`SingleOrDefault`:

```
  var pen = db.Pens.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
```

Your current code has several problems:

- `query` will have type of `IQueryable<T>` (where T is type of pen.Type property). This value cannot be converted to integer
- `id` should not be nullable if you are searching by primary key
- if `num` is integer, then return type of method should be `int` instead of `string`

Comment: :The 'type' property on 'Pen' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Decimal'. How can i resolve this?

Comment: @user3272054 what is definition of Pen class?

Comment: @user3272054 Decimal type does not have property ID

Comment: Thank you so much, yeah got it figured out now. I really appreciate your quick responses. And sorry i don't have enough Reputations to vote up your answer.